# For Android fragment on replace, how to achieve behaviou of onPause() for previous fragment as activity works

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onpause

As per I know and read on fragments, while replacing to new fragment class from one, onPause will not get call unless its onPause() call for activity.

My current need is to stop some listeners of Fragment A when I replace it with Fragment B. Fragment A does not call onPause() on redirecting to Fragment B. And when I come back to Fragment A I want to initiate those listener again.

I hope I am clear enough. Let me know if require more detail on it.

Thanking you in anticipation.
Vyoma

Answer (score 0):

Set any listeners in `onAttach()` method of the fragment and reset them in `onDetach()` method. Because when you replace any fragment `onDetach()` will be invoked for the replaced fragment.

Comment: I tried putting onDetach on Fragment A  but while debug onDetach() is not getting invoked on replacing with Fragment B

Comment: Then try doing it in onDestroyView().

Comment: In that you need to paste some code and explain your issue.